# How to match text in-between a character pattern with regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

Below is the text that I have:

```
Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Praesent commodo cursus magna,
vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. 
Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
|------|------| 
|6 | TEXT | 
|7 | TEXT | 
|8,9 | TEXT | 
|------|------|
Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Praesent commodo cursus magna,
vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra
```

I want to match this bit how would I do with a regular expression?

```
|6 | TEXT | 
|7 | TEXT | 
|8,9 | TEXT |
```

[Here is what I have so far](http://regexr.com/3cnp2)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @ne1410s Nice edit, but there are two more.

Comment: You need to be more explicit about the rules for determining the match. Do you want to match anything that is between two lines `|------|------|` or must the lines of text to be matched have the the specific form as in your example (i.e., `|` followed by one positive integer or two or more positive intergers followed by...)? In the latter case must the text to be matched  be bracketed by the line `|------|------|`? Is it important that a regular expression be used or are you just assuming that's the only way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

The following matches what you need

```
\|\d(,\d)* \| .+ \|
```

It matches a `|` then a digit, then zero or more `,` and digit, then `|`, then any text, then `|`

As shown here: https://regex101.com/r/eB0vI3/2

Comment: Not sure why that was down voted.  Looks fine to me.

Comment: I think it is because of `[A-z]` (that does not match only letters) and in general we do not know what is in between `|` and `|`. And no idea how big the integer part can be.

Comment: Regular expression by itself is just an object. It does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Must you use a regular expression? If your string is `str`, you can write;

```
puts str.split('|------|------|')[1]
  # |6 | TEXT | 
  # |7 | TEXT | 
  # |8,9 | TEXT |
```

Comment: Oh, you used a fixed form.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.split(/^[-|]+\s*\n/)[1]
```

............

Comment: Downvoted for "....." in place of explanatory text. I know you're a good writer, @sawa. You can do so much better.

Answer (score 0):

I would use your current pattern as a delimiter and use the lazy dot matching pattern to match the subtexts you need (using a capturing group in the pattern around that subtext with `String#scan`):

```
/^\|-+\|-+\|\p{Zs}*\s*(.*?)(?=\s*^\|-+\|-+\|)/m
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oA6tU5/3). I added some more subpatterns to "trim" the output "on the fly". `/m` modifier is used to make a `.` match any character including a newline. `^\|-+\|-+\|\p{Zs}*\s*` will match the leading delimiter, `(.*?)` will match and capture the shortest string up to the next delimiter, and `(?=\s*^\|-+\|-+\|)` will not be consumed (in case you want overlapping matches). Remove `(?=` and the last `)` to avoid overlapping matches.

```
rx = /^\|-+\|-+\|\p{Zs}*\s*(.*?)(?=\s*^\|-+\|-+\|)/m
s = "Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.\n|------|------| \n|6 | TEXT | \n|7 | TEXT | \n|8,9 | TEXT | \n|------|------|\nEtiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Praesent commodo cursus magna,\nvel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra "
puts s.scan(rx)
```

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/qNzYU0)

Comment: `\h` doesn't exist in Ruby.

Comment: Okey-dokey, still, `\p{Zs}` is there.